# dropping empty columns in pandas 0.23+

Tags: python, pandas

In earlier versions of pandas, you could drop empty columns simply with:

```
df.dropna(axis='columns')
```

However, dropna has been depreciated in later builds. How would one now drop multiple (without specifically indexing) empty columns from a dataframe?

Comment: dropna is not deprecated, only passing axis=1 is. And the deprication message ("Pass tuple or list to drop on multiple axes.") made no sense to me. Any idea what they are talking about?

Comment: Where did you see that `dropna` is duplicated?

Comment: @RafaelC https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html I assumed it wasn't working because of this, but axis=1 didn't work either.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I am able to drop empty columns using `dropna()` with the current version of Pandas (0.23.4). The code I used is:

```
df.dropna(how='all', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Looks like what is deprecated is passing multiple axes at once (i.e. `df.dropna(how='all', axis = [0, 1]`). You can read [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20987) that they made this decision - "let's deprecate passing multiple axes, we don't do this for any other pandas functions".

Comment: I keep forgetting `inplace`. This works for me `df.dropna(inplace=True, axis=1, how='all')`

Answer (score 6):

You can get the columns that are not null and then filter your DataFrame on those.

Here's an example

```
non_null_columns = [col for col in df.columns if df.loc[:, col].notna().any()]
df[non_null_columns]
```