# How do I read an excel using pandas to_excel method, till a specific column?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, worksheet-function

I have an excel which has 100 columns, but has data till a specific column only. (it is a monthly file and data gets appended to the file every month at the end in the column name which is month name.

**How to I select that specific column which has recently populated data.**

This is the following piece of code that i used to get the last column, but it returns the 100th column, which for obvious reasons, is empty

```
   workbook = load_workbook(filename=Input_directory + '\\' +File_name)  
   worksheet = workbook.active
   worksheet.max_column
```

**Is there any way where i can get the column value of the excel till which it has data.**

Thanks

Comment: What if you drop all empty columns instantly right after you import your dataframe? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51794989/9758194)

Comment: That can be a workaround, but i would not like to load the whole excel at first place